# String Manipulation with CSS in Mail (hack)

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

Is there a simple way to remove or make invisible two characters from the beginning of a string using just html and css? You can keep for yourself the downvotes to the questions... I know it's a hack.

I'm using mailchimp to send abandoned cart reminder mails. The price of a product is displayed as

```
zl123
```

but I need to display it as

```
123 zl
```

I tried to change the settings of the money format, but I haven't found a solution, so I'll try to hack it in some other way. Mailchimp replaces automatically a placeholder so I have to process what they put instead of the price placeholder, I have no control on that.

I have an html mail template and I can use css with it but no javascript. If you know how to solve the format problem in the mailchimp settings directly it will also work of course. Any help is very appreciated.

This is the product list code and the tag is *|PRODUCT:PRICE|*:

```
*|ABANDONED_CART:[$total=3]|*
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top" valign="top" width="80"><a href="*|CART:URL|*" style="max-width: 80px; text-decoation: none !important" target="_blank"><img src="*|PRODUCT:IMAGE_URL|*" /> </a></td>
      <td style="padding: 10px 30px"><a class="ab-cart__name" href="*|CART:URL|*" target="_blank">*|PRODUCT:TITLE|*:</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px 30px"><a class="ab-cart__price" href="*|CART:URL|*" target="_blank">*|PRODUCT:PRICE|*</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px 30px">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#bed22c;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:9px 20px; padding-right:5px" valign="middle"><a class="ab-cart__button" href="*|CART:URL|*" target="_blank"><img class="ab-cart__icon" data-file-id="1415814" height="13" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6b8c9d4b13e018d718abc0a65/images/2226adf6-5cc3-4f24-aa98-39825c247c2c.png" width="14" /> </a></td>
            <td style="padding:9px 0; padding-right:10px"><a class="ab-cart__button" href="*|CART:URL|*" target="_blank">Zobacz w koszyku </a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
*|END:ABANDONED_CART|*
```

Comment: share your html code

Comment: Have you considered changing the HTML mail template?

Comment: Neither HTML nor CSS is a programming language so they should never be treated as one that can do such a thing.

Comment: could you show the markup of the relevant part?

Comment: just edited in the code

Comment: and where is the part that show what you have ?

Comment: please show the exact markup printed out in place of *|PRODUCT:PRICE|*:

Comment: *|PRODUCT:PRICE|* is replaced by mailchimp automatically, so just assume zl123 is written there and I cannot change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky way will be fixing and repeating the word twice!

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.hide-first-two {
  text-indent: -0.75em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show-first-two {
  width: 0.75em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="hide-first-two">zl123</span>
  <span class="show-first-two">zl123</span>
</p>
```

Or using inline style:

```html
<p style="font-size: 20px;">
  <span style="text-indent: -0.75em; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">zl123</span>
  <span style="width: 0.75em; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">zl123</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That's a visual manipulation, not textual, and it might not work in an email.

Comment: That's what you can achieve with HTML and CSS right?

Comment: @Rob inlining the style will have the same result

Comment: then it's not possible unless he uses javascript, as far as I understand

Comment: I wrote "remove or make invisible", if this works I'm ok.

Comment: @JoseAPL will this hide exactly the first 2 chars or just a piece of the text depending on the font size?

Comment: @GismoRanas it will hide the two first characters relative to the font size applied to ‘<p>’ if it would have three characters then you increase the ‘text-indent’ and the ‘width’ values, but if you change the ‘font-size’ then you don’t have to modify anything

Answer (score 0):

> Considering your text `lz123` comming form server and appened in
>   `<p>lz123</p>`

- You can add text in this `<p>` by using `::after` and  `::before` css selectors
- But if is not possible to remove or manipulate that text in `<p>` using css

**For string manipulation i suggest to use Javascript or Jquery**

Comment: thanks, do you mind to elaborate on your css solution? I explicitly wrote I cannot use js because it's a mail.

Comment: That only visually moves them. It does not move them within the string and might not work in email.

Comment: @GismoRanas , you can manipulate that string at server level before triggering mail to users.

Comment: as I wrote I cannot change the string at server level. I send them 123 and they send back zl123